# Why do errors don't appear in Error List tab?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Errors don't appear in Error List tab but they do appear in Output tab where line error is not listed, screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because there's no errors, warnings or other messages for the "Current Document"? Anyways, for full context you need to check the "Output" tab anyway.

Comment: All right, i use to have a message box that would appear everytime i compiled and link that would prompt me with a "yes" and a "no", do you know how i can have this message box back ?

Comment: Could you try clicking on the text where it says "0 of 4 Errors" same thing with the "0 of 1 Warnings"? This will toggle between showing/hiding errors and warnings.

Comment: Yes i did, clicking won't show the errors that i can see(with no line description) on the output tab, warnings are shown when clicking.